# Scipy: sampled data points are of similar value

Tags: python, random, scipy

I want to randomly sample from a custom function using scipy in the range 0.15 to 10.1. However, my sample is highly skewed towards the left boundary of 0.15. In fact, all of the 50000 sampled points are less than 0.16. I'm not sure what the problem is with my code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

class your_distribution(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        p0 = 10.9949;
        p1 = 0.394447;
        p2 = 12818.4;
        p3 = 2.38898;
        return ((p1*p3)/(p3*p0+p2*p1))*(p0*np.exp(-1.0*p1*x))+(p2*np.exp(-1.0*p3*x))

distribution = your_distribution(a=0.15, b=10.1)
sample = distribution.rvs(size=50000)
```

Comment: It is not. All points in my sample are 0.15, but if you plot the pdf you will see that there is good probability that I should be sampling points as high as 1.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that you implemented as `_pdf()` is not a PDF.  To be a PDF, the integral over [a, b] must be 1.  The integral of your PDF is not 1, it is approximately 3750:

```
In [27]: from scipy.integrate import quad

In [28]: quad(distribution.pdf, distribution.a, distribution.b)
Out[28]: (3749.6759222061523, 6.886284755966421e-09)
```

If, as a quick hack, I modify your distribution as follows:

```
class your_distribution(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        p0 = 10.9949;
        p1 = 0.394447;
        p2 = 12818.4;
        p3 = 2.38898;
        p = ((p1*p3)/(p3*p0+p2*p1))*(p0*np.exp(-1.0*p1*x))+(p2*np.exp(-1.0*p3*x))
        return p / 3749.6759222061523
```

Then it works as expected.

(It is a quick hack because the normalizing constant should depend on `a` and `b` in general.)

Comment: Yes, that fixes the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code. The problem is probably with the definition of your distribution. This grows asymptotically large as `x` becomes smaller. Therefore, since you specify your lower bound of the support of the distribution to be `a=0.15` this value would correspond to asymptotically probability `1`.

**Note that the lower bound of the support, is not the lower bound of `x`**

If you plot the `pdf` you can check that it receives almost all its mass from points around `x = -292`. By specifying `a=0.15` in effect you move that spike of probability to `0.15`

I suspect what you want to achieve is a distribution where the probability for `x<0.15` is zero. This can be achieved by modifying your custom distribution as follows

```
class your_distribution(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x):
        p0 = 10.9949;
        p1 = 0.394447;
        p2 = 12818.4;
        p3 = 2.38898;
        if x < 0.15:
            return 0
        return ((p1*p3)/(p3*p0+p2*p1))*(p0*np.exp(-1.0*p1*x))+(p2*np.exp(-1.0*p3*x))
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem as all of my sampled points are still 0.15.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem (with some help from a friend)!

It turns out my pdf wasn't normalized properly because I was missing a bracket. The correct pdf is `((p1*p3)/(p3*p0+p2*p1))*((p0*np.exp(-1.0*p1*x))+(p2*np.exp(-1.0*p3*x)))`.